# Encrypt assets (JSON) using DexGuard

Tags: android, android-assets, dexguard

I am using DexGuard v7.3.18 and I want to encrypt JSON files that are stored in `assets/json` which I access in my classes like so:

`inputstream = context.getAssets().open("json/" + jsonFileName)`

and I configured `dexguard-project.pro` with various options like:

1. `-encryptassetfiles assets/json/**.json`
2. `-encryptassetfiles assets/json/**`

but neither helped to encrypt the JSON files. According to DexGuard docs:

> -encryptassetfiles [file_filter]
>   Specifies the Android asset files that should be encrypted. Asset files are stored in the assets directory and can contain any data. The obfuscation step can automatically encrypt them and make sure they are decrypted on the fly at run-time. In order for this to work, the asset files must be streamed and their names must be specified as string constants. This means that your code must invoke the AsssetManager as follows:
>   `open("MyAssetFile")`
>   Your configuration can then specify "-encryptassetfiles assets/MyAssetFile". Only applicable when obfuscating Android code.

I verified the configured APK using `Apktool`. What am I missing?

Comment: You use a program on your pc to encrypt an assets file in an apk file?

Comment: No, encryption is handled by DexGuard.

Comment: It is totally unclear to what you want to happen.

Comment: I'm not sure which part is unclear. My question is simple - DexGuard provides asset encryption and I want to know how the options should be set up to enable asset encryption and I specified the options I tried that didn't work as expected.

Comment: If you are not using a program on your pc to encrypt a file in assets of a apk file, then what are you doing? What is happening? When? Where? Totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need specifically load the asset files this way for Dexguard to encrypt your meson files:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();  
InputStream is = assetManager.open("json/file1.json");
InputStream is2 = assetManager.open("json/file2.json");
.......(individually load each file)
```

In other words, file names must specifically appears in each open method as constant string.

Otherwise, Dexguard will not encrypt the files or the encrypted files won't get decrypted correctly.